# What is contained in these addresses?

Tags: linux, kernel, kvm, virtual-memory

I am working on MUlti-processor record-replay feature of a virtual machine.
I have a log of non-deterministic memory access done in the virtual machine by virtual CPUs.
A very high proportion of these point to kernel space memory ie above 0Xc0000000.
For example heres a list of 10 most  accessed kernel memory address  after running SPLASH benchmark in the Virtual machine

```
0xfffb5000                                                    
0xc1779db0                                               
0xc18b6910                                                      
0xc1771a44                                                      
0xc1771a40                                                      
0xc1779e00                                                      
0xc18b67e0                                                      
0xc18b693c                                                      
0xc18b67f0                                                      
0xfffa1000
```

I want to know if there is some way of finding what exactly are in these memory address ... is it the kernel stack , vsyscall page, scheduler's ready list ...
So that i can then think of some way of solving this overhead to speed up record replay....
Hints to where to look in the kernel code is welcome

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On a physical machine I would take a look at /boot/System.map* (whatever that file is called in your distribution).

My guess is that the same is true within a KVM VM.

Answer (score 1):

KVM-QEMU supports debugging - you can connect to the virtual machine with `gdb` and see what's happening in there (you'll need to set up the debug symbols properly of course).

Answer (score 0):

Well ,
  some of the address point to static data in the kernel Ex incrementers used by seqlocks ..
An `objdump` of the kernel reveals about half of these address, but for the ones which are stored on stack and heap objdump is of no use ...

`cat /proc/kallsysm` 
reveals all variable/functions which were exported by the module containing it.

I dont think we can know what was stored in those locations ....